# SpeechAPI голос google

Tags: javascript, браузер, text-to-speech

Подскажите!

Столкнулся с проблемой при изучении и не могу найти ответа в сети. Написал простое приложение для чтения текста голосом при помощи speechapi вот кусок кода:

```
  const speakText = (text) => {
    const utterText = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(inputText);
    utterText.voice = voicesList[currentVoice];
    synth.speak(utterText);
   
    utterText.onstart = () => setIsSpeaking(true);
    utterText.onend = () => setIsSpeaking(false);
  };
```

Все работает отлично если выбираю голос Microsoft Irina весь текст читает полностью, если выбираю Google русский то через какое-то время звук обрывается, при этом нет ошибок в консоли и не срабатывают колбеки onpause onend onerror. с телефона (android) даже не хочет воспроизводить если текст большой короткий текст нормально.

***Вопрос:***

Есть ли какие-то ограничения на использование голоса google (время, количество слов или букв) ? и если да то где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: Возможно, [здесь](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas) написано об ограничении в 1 минуту или в 5 минут

Comment: это скорее всего про google Cloud Speech-to-Text у меня наоборот, да и обрываеться быстрее гдето секунд 20. Я просто использую стандартный `window.speechSynthesis` без регистраций, платных апи, ключей и.т.д..

Comment: [32767 символов?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/text)

Comment: нет меньше, точно не замерял, это видимо ограничение на строку и 32к довольно много.с компа просто звук обрывает а с мобилы читать не хочет если много текста любой голос от гугла видимо где флаг localService = false.

Comment: само ограничение я конечно обошел разбив текст на меньшие куски и проигрывая кусками. но появляется неприятная уху пауза между кусками. просто хотел больше узнать про такое ограничение если оно есть, даже в примерах кода от гугла ничего об этом не сказано

Comment: А проведите тест: найдите максимальную длину читаемого текста, добавьте к тексту ещё пару слов или букв и проверьте функции обратного вызова. Тогда будет ясно, что всё работает "нормально" и не уходит в какой-нибудь бесконечный цикл внутри (может ли ошибка быть в устройстве?)